# SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing.(with open('myfile.txt',mode='a') as p:)

Tags: python, python-3.7

I am getting "SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing" even though my syntax is correct. how can i correct it?

```
%%writefile mynewfile.txt
L stands for Lamborghini
M stands for Maserati
A stands for Audi
```

```
with open('myfile.txt', mode = 'r') as newfile:
     print(newfile.read())

with open('myfile.txt',mode='a') as p:
```

```
File "<ipython-input-24-c4ad87f5e304>", line 1
    with open('myfile.txt',mode='a') as p:
                                          ^
SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing
```

Comment: dont you think you need to finish this open statement after `:`

Comment: Your syntax isn't correct. A with statement requires a block. Your second ``with`` doesn't have one.

Comment: "even though my syntax is correct"? If the interpreter is telling you it isn't, who do you think is more likely to be right? :) -- which is to say, "even though my syntax is correct *as far as I know*" would be way to write this that comes off as having more humility, rather than asserting that the blame is on the system and not yourself.

Comment: I just thought it was correct. You think you are a super programmer who codes for satellites? Nah nah kiddo:)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
with open('myfile.txt', mode = 'r') as newfile:
     print(newfile.read())

with open('myfile.txt',mode='a') as p:
     pass
```

Python doesn't allow empty blocks in `while` / `for` / `if` statements.

Comment: Thank you Radoslaw Cybulski